# Routing with permalinks of two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

i have 2 models, which look like this:

```
Category:
id
name
permalink
```

e.g. 1 "Foo Bar" foo-bar

```
Item: 
id
title
permalink
category_id
```

so there is an association between these two models. now i want achieve the following route:

```
http://www.bla.com/Category_permalink/Item_ID/Item_permalink
```

what i have now, and that's incorrect is the following:

```
match ':category_name/:item_id/:item_permalink' => 'items#show', :as => :item
```

this line doesn't work as expected. any advice here?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your goal to generate the path by use ``item_path(@item)`` given the ``@item`` instance?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like more of a problem with how you are trying to access the route than the route itself.  Can you run rake routes and post the response here? The relevant controller and view code would probably be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure what you would like to achieve, but I think you could always use `item_path(:category_name => item.category.name, :item_id => item.id, :item_permalink => item.permalink)` to get that link.